# First appearance of the term sinus cardinalis

Tags: terminology

Who introduced the term sinus cardinalis? I do not mean the abbreviation sinc, which was introduced 1952 by Woodward.

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830070/18398

Answer (score 2):

According to sources quoted in Wikipedia's `sinc` "talk" page,

> The name sinus cardinalis dates back by Edmund T. Whittaker in 1915,
>   where he named the bandlimited or most simple function of a family of
>   cotabular functions (sharing a function table, i.e., values at equally
>   spaced sample points) the cardinal function of this family. One would
>   have to check if he already named the basis functions or if that came
>   later. See A History of interpolation.--LutzL (talk)

Following that "talk" link leads to [a history page](https://imagescience.org/meijering/research/chronology/)  which includes an image from that paper, From E. T. Whittaker, "On the Functions which are Represented by the Expansions of Interpolation-Theory", Proceedings of the Royal Society of Edinburgh, vol. 35, 1915, pp. 181-194

[image: whittaker excerpt]

Comment: The Wikipedia page doesn’t say that, nor do the words “cardinal” or “cardinalis” appear in the quoted [1952 paper](https://doi.org/10.1049/pi-3.1952.0011) and [1953 book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=mdp.39015000489735&num=29).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler  I stand corrected -- the text of the WIki page was rather misleading.   I'll try to update my answer shortly

Comment: I think you’re right that the name “cardinal” for interpolation series [goes back to Whittaker](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1971-0301428-0). But who first called ***the sinc function*** “cardinal sine” remains anyone’s guess. Whittaker ([1915](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0370164600017806)) certainly doesn’t, nor does Woodward imply that “c” is for cardinal.